# Writing and Updating ~8K-10K Iterations of URLs Strings on a Text File (PHP, Performance, CRON)

Tags: php, string, performance, file, filesystems

#### Problem

I have tried to write an only list-urls sitemap on a `txt` file. A file is generated daily and can be updated.

#### Trial

`generateSitemap` is part of a large class `UpdateStocks` which gets an input string and writes a URL for that input iterating about ~8-10K. Inputs are being generated using data from an API right before going to `generateSitemap`.

#### Performance

Would you be so kind and help me to possibly make it faster, simpler or more efficient? There is a small bug in `generateSitemap` that I could not find out, when it updates the file, sometimes, there is an extra newline `\n` in the `txt` file.

#### Pseudocode that calls the `generateSitemap`

```
{pseudocode} for i=1 to 8000;
    generate input[i]; // for example: 'aapl-apple-technology-nasdaq-us-8f4c'
    UpdateStocks::generateSitemap(input[i]);
{/pseudocode} endfor;
```

#### Class Constant

```
const DIR_URL_KEYWORD_1 = "equity";
const DIR_URL_KEYWORD_2 = "equilibrium-estimation";
const DOMAIN = "domain.org";
const EXTENSION_MD = ".md";
const EXTENSION_TXT = ".txt";
const NEW_LINE = "\n";
const PROTOCOL = "https://";
const SITEMAP_PREFIX = "/sitemap-";
const SLASH = "/";
```

#### generateSitemap

```
  /**
   * 
   * @return a large string in a txt file including all urls for a daily sitemap
   */
  public static function generateSitemap($lurl){
    $dir=__DIR__ . self::DIR_FRONT_PUBLIC_HTML;

    // url
    $sm=sprintf('%s%s%s',
                self::PROTOCOL.self::DOMAIN.self::SLASH.self::DIR_URL_KEYWORD_1.self::SLASH.self::DIR_URL_KEYWORD_2.self::SLASH,
                $lurl,
                self::NEW_LINE
        );
    $dt=new \DateTime('now');
    $dt=$dt->format('Y-m-d'); // today
    $fn=$dir . self::SITEMAP_PREFIX . $dt . self::EXTENSION_TXT; // sitemap filename in public_html

    // if daily sitemap already exits
    if(file_exists($fn)){
      $arr = preg_split('/\n/', trim(file_get_contents($fn))); // array of links
      $i=0; // counter
      foreach ($arr as $k=>$lk){
        if($arr[$k]==null){unset($arr[$k]);}
        if(trim($lk)===trim($sm)){ // link already exist
          $i++;
          if($i>0){$arr[$k]=null;} // link already exist more than once
        }else{
          if($k==sizeof($arr)-1){
            $k++;
            $arr[$k]=$sm;
            $arr=implode(self::NEW_LINE, $arr);
            $fh=fopen($fn, 'wb');
            fwrite($fh, $arr);
            fclose($fh);
          }
          continue;
        }
      }
    }else{
      $fh=fopen($fn, 'wb');
      fwrite($fh, $sm);
      fclose($fh);
    }    
  }
```

#### Example of Inputs

```
a-agilent-technologies-healthcare-nyse-us-39d4
aa-alcoa-basic-materials-nyse-us-159a
aaau-perth-mint-physical-gold-nyse-us-8ed9
aaba-altaba-financial-services-nasdaq-us-26f5
aac-healthcare-nyse-us-e92a
aadr-advisorshares-dorsey-wright-adr-nyse-us-d842
aal-airlines-industrials-nasdaq-us-29eb
aamc-altisource-asset-management-com-financial-services-nyse-us-b46a
aan-aarons-industrials-nyse-us-d00e
aaoi-applied-optoelectronics-technology-nasdaq-us-1dee
aaon-basic-materials-nasdaq-us-238e
aap-advance-auto-parts-wi-consumer-cyclical-nyse-us-1f60
aapl-apple-technology-nasdaq-us-8f4c
aat-assets-real-estate-nyse-us-3598
aau-almaden-minerals-basic-materials-nyse-us-1c57
aaww-atlas-air-worldwide-industrials-nasdaq-us-69f3
aaxj-ishares-msci-all-country-asia-ex-japan-nasdaq-us-c6c4
aaxn-axon-enterprise-industrials-nasdaq-us-0eef
ab-alliancebernstein-units-financial-services-nyse-us-deb1
abac-renmin-tianli-consumer-defensive-nasdaq-us-8701
abb-industrials-nyse-us-a407
abbv-abbvie-healthcare-nyse-us-9aea
abc-amerisourcebergen-healthcare-nyse-us-bd9d
abcb-ameris-bancorp-financial-services-nasdaq-us-df98
abdc-alcentra-capital-financial-services-nasdaq-us-96dd
abeo-abeona-therapeutics-healthcare-nasdaq-us-aa0f
abeow-market-us-d84d
abev-ambev-1-consumer-defensive-nyse-us-a9b4
abg-asbury-automotive-consumer-cyclical-nyse-us-db5f
abil-ability-technology-nasdaq-us-91a6
abio-arca-biopharma-healthcare-nasdaq-us-098e
abm-abm-industries-industrials-nyse-us-bcbc
abmd-abiomed-healthcare-nasdaq-us-2818
abr-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-68b1
abr-a-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-8c1d
abr-b-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-97f2
abr-c-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-ee81
abt-abbott-laboratories-healthcare-nyse-us-c7fd
abtx-allegiance-bancshares-financial-services-nasdaq-us-6913
abus-arbutus-biopharma-healthcare-nasdaq-us-c23f
ac-associated-capital-financial-services-nyse-us-fca3
aca-arcosa-industrials-nyse-us-b429
```

#### Part of sitemap-2019-03-15.txt:

```
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/a-agilent-technologies-healthcare-nyse-us-39d4
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aa-alcoa-basic-materials-nyse-us-159a
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aaau-perth-mint-physical-gold-nyse-us-8ed9
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aaba-altaba-financial-services-nasdaq-us-26f5
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aac-healthcare-nyse-us-e92a
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aadr-advisorshares-dorsey-wright-adr-nyse-us-d842
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aal-airlines-industrials-nasdaq-us-29eb
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aamc-altisource-asset-management-com-financial-services-nyse-us-b46a
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aan-aarons-industrials-nyse-us-d00e
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aaoi-applied-optoelectronics-technology-nasdaq-us-1dee
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aaon-basic-materials-nasdaq-us-238e
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aap-advance-auto-parts-wi-consumer-cyclical-nyse-us-1f60
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aapl-apple-technology-nasdaq-us-8f4c
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aat-assets-real-estate-nyse-us-3598
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aau-almaden-minerals-basic-materials-nyse-us-1c57
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aaww-atlas-air-worldwide-industrials-nasdaq-us-69f3
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aaxj-ishares-msci-all-country-asia-ex-japan-nasdaq-us-c6c4
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aaxn-axon-enterprise-industrials-nasdaq-us-0eef
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/ab-alliancebernstein-units-financial-services-nyse-us-deb1
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abac-renmin-tianli-consumer-defensive-nasdaq-us-8701
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abb-industrials-nyse-us-a407
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abbv-abbvie-healthcare-nyse-us-9aea
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abc-amerisourcebergen-healthcare-nyse-us-bd9d
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abcb-ameris-bancorp-financial-services-nasdaq-us-df98
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abdc-alcentra-capital-financial-services-nasdaq-us-96dd
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abeo-abeona-therapeutics-healthcare-nasdaq-us-aa0f
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abeow-market-us-d84d
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abev-ambev-1-consumer-defensive-nyse-us-a9b4
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abg-asbury-automotive-consumer-cyclical-nyse-us-db5f
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abil-ability-technology-nasdaq-us-91a6
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abio-arca-biopharma-healthcare-nasdaq-us-098e
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abm-abm-industries-industrials-nyse-us-bcbc
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abmd-abiomed-healthcare-nasdaq-us-2818
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abr-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-68b1
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abr-a-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-8c1d
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abr-b-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-97f2
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abr-c-arbor-realty-real-estate-nyse-us-ee81
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abt-abbott-laboratories-healthcare-nyse-us-c7fd
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abtx-allegiance-bancshares-financial-services-nasdaq-us-6913
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/abus-arbutus-biopharma-healthcare-nasdaq-us-c23f
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/ac-associated-capital-financial-services-nyse-us-fca3
domain.org/equity/equilibrium-estimation/aca-arcosa-industrials-nyse-us-b429
```

Comment: So, you just want to extract the individual strings, remove duplicates, then append a static string to each unique value? Yes, this can be tuned up.  It will take me a moment on my phone.

Comment: I'm still reading over your script... you mean to tell us that you are calling the method (`UpdateStocks::generateSitemap(input[i]);`) 8000 times?!?. You should definitely NOT be opening,writing,closing your file 8000 times.  You should only be writing to the file ONCE after all of the processing is done. Do you actually need regex? Or can you just explode on `\n`?  If you have lingering whitespaces, you can split on `\s+`.

Comment: The correction to your code is too large for me to bother on my phone, I'll get to my computer later.  Where is `domain.org/url[0]/url[1]/` generated in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an untested script that embodies how I would run it (unless we are dealing with prohibitively large file sizes).

Collect and prepare all of api strings into a single array.

If the first data of the day, just push the data into a new file.

If the file exists, extract the old data, merge with the new, purge the duplicates, alphabetize, then replace the file contents.

```
public static function collectAPIData() {
    $leading_url = self::PROTOCOL .
                   self::DOMAIN .
                   self::SLASH . 
                   self::DIR_URL_KEYWORD_1 .
                   self::SLASH .
                   self::DIR_URL_KEYWORD_2 .
                   self::SLASH;
    $fresh_data = [];
    // start loop
        $fresh_data[] = $leading_url . $your_string_from_the_api;
    // end loop
    return $fresh_data;
}

public static function storeSitemapData($new_urls) {
    if (!$new_urls)) {
        return;
    }
    $fn = __DIR__ . 
          self::DIR_FRONT_PUBLIC_HTML .
          self::SITEMAP_PREFIX .
          (new \DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d') .
          self::EXTENSION_TXT; 

    if (file_exists($fn)) {
        $old_urls = file($fn, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        $merged = array_merge($old_urls, $new_urls);
        $unique = array_keys(array_flip($merged));
        sort($unique);
        $new_urls = $unique;
    }
    file_put_contents($fn, implode(self::NEW_LINE, $new_urls));
}
```

These static functions could be called something like this:

```
UpdateStocks::storeSitemapData(UpdateStocks::collectAPIData));
```

In truth, for higher efficiency I could have differentiated new unique urls, then appended them to the existing file, but I like the idea of keeping the data alphabetized.

Comment: I won't be at my computer for a while, so I hacked something together on my phone.  Let me know if it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0; // counter 
foreach ($arr as $k=>$lk){ 
if($arr[$k]==null)
{unset($arr[$k]);} 
if(trim($lk)===trim($sm))
{ 
if($i>0){$arr[$k]=null;}
$i++;  
}
```

$i++ should  come after if statement

Comment: Please continue to edit/improve this answer to use proper tabbing and some explanation.

Comment: I tried already there is a problem with your loop iteration once loop is going as empty value thats why you are getting new blank line